# Phaser sound stops working only on Chrome for Android

Tags: google-chrome, phaser-framework

The sound works for the first few minutes but after a while .play() doesn't play any sound.  It seems like if there is a huge duration where no sound has played the sound stops working.

It works fine on Desktop, iOS and the generic android browser.  I'm just running into this problem specifically on android devices using mobile chrome as the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of phaser and android do you have? For me it seems to play without issues for a 4-minute song i tried. Even if the screen goes of, it continues without any problem when it is resumed. A dirty solution will be to add an loop that plays a silent sound every 2 minutes for example just to "refresh" the sound manager if that solves your problem.

Comment: I am using Phaser v2.1.3 with Canvas and Webaudio.  I added a 1 second blank sound file to loop every 30 seconds to refresh the web audio context.  That did the trick.  I did notice a resume for the audio context but I couldn't get it to work.  I tried something like 
`sound.context.resume().then(function(){ sound.play()});` but that didn't work.  I probably need a better understanding on how the audiocontext works

Comment: Maybe it's a version bug. I tried both 2.4.3 and 2.4.4 and it seems to work. Glad the workaround solved your problem though!

Answer (score 2):

This turns out to be a Chrome bug that causes web audio to stop playing sounds if no sound has played for something like 30 seconds.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=518863

The fix seems to be to watch

audioContext.currentTime

and when it gets stuck after 30 secs create a new audioContext.

The solution I ended up using is as follows:

Note I am using the phaser library - so this exact solution wont work for you - but it will give you the general idea

```
//This is run using a timer event every second

//this.game.time.events.loop(1000, this.checkAudioContext, this);

evil.AudioManager.prototype.checkAudioContext=function(){

    //work out when the audio context has stopped

    if(this.game.sound.context.currentTime-this.last_context_time===0){

        //close out the existing context and create a new one
        //you will also need new gain nodes if you are using them

        this.game.sound.context.close();  
        this.game.sound.context=new AudioContext(); 
        this.game.sound.masterGain= this.game.sound.context.createGain(); 
        this.game.sound.masterGain.gain.volume=this.volume;
        this.game.sound.masterGain.connect(this.game.sound.context.destination);

        //now go through every sound and connect them to the new context
        //creating gain nodes as we go.
        for(var key in this.tracks){

            var snd=this.tracks[key].snd;
            snd.context=this.game.sound.context;
            snd.masterGainNode = this.game.sound.masterGain;
            snd.gainNode=this.game.sound.context.createGain();          
            snd.gainNode.gain.value = snd.volume * this.volume;
            snd.gainNode.connect(snd.masterGainNode);
        }       

    }else{
    //update out time variable
    this.last_context_time=ctx.currentTime;
    }
}
```